# Does Hibernate Transaction Rollback working?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rollback

I have 2 model classes: ModelA & ModelB

2 persistent classes: ModelADAO & ModelBDAO. In each implementation for it, I did use transaction rollback for save(model) method. Basically as following:

```
public class ModelADAOImpl implements ModelADAO {

    public bool save(modelA) {

        try {
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            ...

            session.persist(modelA);

            ...
            transaction.commit();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();

        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

}

public class ModelBDAOImpl implements ModelBDAO {

    public bool save(modelB) {

        try {
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            ...

            session.persist(modelB);

            ...
            transaction.commit();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();

        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Now, I have other class with ***saveAll(modelA, modelB)*** method to save information for both **modelA** and **modelB** by calling ***modelADAO.save(modelA)*** and ***modelBDAO.save(modelB)***.

```
public class WrapperDAOImpl implements WrapperDAO {

    @Autowired
    private ModelADAO modelADAO;

    @Autowired
    private ModelBDAO modelBDAO;

    public bool saveAll(modelA, modelB) {

        try {
            ...

            modelADAO.save(modelA);
            modelBDAO.save(modelB);

            ...

        } catch(Exception e) {
            ...

        } finally {
            ...
        }
    }

}
```

How can I apply rolling back for saveAll(modelA, modelB) in this case? Because I did open and close session in each save() method.

Thanks!

Trong.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to change the way you build your DAO's. I never do transaction management inside DAO's, instead, I manage transactions on service layer.

It is common that a service method need to call several DAO's methods, and thus you want to apply a single transaction for all, as you state in your question.

So, I will move transaction management to `saveAll` method. Obviously, this change could lead you to an error, if a DAO save method is calling without managing transaction. That's why I am telling you to use a service layer.

Another option, to leave transaction management inside DAO's, could be using transaction propagation, with `PROPAGATION=required`. However I've never used it and not sure how it works, but at least in theory it is supposed that this way, if there is no transaction created when invoking `save` method, it will be created, but if there is an already created transaction it will use it. A rollback will undo all changes.

Comment: I agree with you that Transaction should be put on Service layer. But I don't want to refactor current code because the system is running with them. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution which most frameworks apply is to track the running transaction by thread, so you keep a thread-local with the running transaction. Another solution would be to pass the tx around as an argument to your methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your must use generic interface for persisting your data not depends on entityA or entityB.And also for your models you must have a Base bean that hold the id.

```
public class BaseBean{

 private Long id ;
//get + set

}

public class Aa extends BaseBean{

}

public class Bb extends BaseBean{

}

public interface daoRepository{
<T extends BaseBean> void save(Iterable<? extends T> objects);
}


public class daoImpl implements daoRepository{

    @Override
    public <T extends BaseBean> void save(Iterable<? extends T> objects){
      try {
        session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        ...
        for (T t : objects) {
        session.persist(t);
        }
        ...
        transaction.commit();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        transaction.rollback();

    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you said, but I don't want to refactor them because the system is running with those methods.